# Compiling IFCPlusPlus with VS2015 create huge libraries

Tags: visual-studio, boost, ifc

I downloaded IFCPlusPlus on GitHub (https://github.com/ifcquery/ifcplusplus.git).
I set Boost library (1_60_0) and compile the project (IfcPlusPlus.vcxproj) in Visual Studio 2015 (Windows 7).
The generated libraries are huge : carve.lib is 67 Mb large, and ifcplusplus.lib is 2 Gb large !
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions of libraries are right. Use another approch: instead of use ifcplusplus classes, you may create your own ifc c++ classes using CodeSynthesis XSD 4.0 from http://www.codesynthesis.com/ and xsd from http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/downloads/ifc/ifc4/ifcxml4-xsd-longform/view. In this way you have resized dimensions, with the possibility to serialize / deserialize. I hope this may help you. Best regards, fabio.